# simulate('scroll') on a div inside a React component returns `AssertionError: expected false to be true`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, electron, enzyme

I have a React component I'm writing some tests for. I'd like to test that when a `div` in the component is scrolled it triggers the function listening for that event, `onScroll`. Unfortunately Enzyme's `simulate('click')` doesn't seem to call my `spy` function, as I'd expect.

### My component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import jQuery from 'jquery';
const $ = jQuery;

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  handleScroll(event) {
    return true;
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="my-component" onScroll={this.handleScroll}>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

### My Test

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { spy } from 'sinon';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';;

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import MyComponent from '../views/components/my-component';

describe("<MyComponent />", () => {
  it('should trigger pagination when div.search-box scrolls', () => {
    const component = mount(<MyComponent />);
    const handleScrollSpy = spy(component.node, 'handleScroll');
    component
      .find('.my-component')
      .simulate('scroll')

    expect(handleScrollSpy.called).to.be.true;
  });
});
```

This returns: `AssertionError: expected false to be true`

I've tried calling the function within the test and it cause the `callCount` to be `1`…

```
component.node.handleScroll();
console.log("Call count: ", handleScrollSpy.callCount);
```

This makes me think the problem with my test is to do with the `simulate` part…

```
component
      .find('.search-box')
      .simulate('click')
```

Can someone confirm for me if i'm approaching this correctly or if i'm indeed doing something wrong, please?

Thanks.

---

#### Edit

Further reading of the Enzyme `.simulate` docs revealed the following:

> Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event,
>   .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the
>   event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get
>   the onClick prop and call it.

I wonder if it's because i'm not passing the `onScroll` as a prop that the `.simulate` isn't triggering the `handleScroll` function at the moment.

Comment: My assumption is "scroll" event is not fired, because there is nothing to scroll in your `div`

Comment: @Torin yeah good point. I've changed this to an `onClick` too though and it still doesn't pass.

Answer (score 1):

I've not used Sinon for spying but it may be worth rewriting your `handleScroll`:

```js
handleScroll = (event) => {
  return true;
}
```

The fat arrow will auto bind 'this' for you, which means you can remove `this.handleScroll = ...` in the constructor.

Another option is to test the result of the `handleScroll` function (this is obviously tricky while it just returns true) rather than testing it was called.

Finally you could test that the component render created a div with the onScroll property set to `this.handleScroll` and then test `handleScroll` separately.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for enzyme but using regular react test utils simulation you have to pass it a deltaY like this:
`TestUtils.Simulate.scroll(wrapper, { deltaY: 500 });`

I would see if you can pass the same deltaY to the .simulate enzyme provides.